# Loading WinRT assembly from .NET

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, windows-runtime

How does one load a WinRT assembly by name? When I do the following:

```
(new TextBlock()).GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly
```

Then I get the assembly Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls. But if I try to load it by name:

```
var name = new AssemblyName { 
   Name = "Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls", 
   Version = new Version(255, 255, 255, 255), 
   ContentType = AssemblyContentType.WindowsRuntime 
};
```

Then it says "Operation not supported". This happens even if I do this:

```
var name = (new TextBlock()).GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName();
Assembly.Load(name);
```

How can I get at WinRT assemblies by name?

Comment: I see, thanks. Even if I do include all that information, as in the third example, that still doesn't fix the problem...

Comment: AssemblyName doesn't actually support culture and publickeytoken? Perhaps this is different in the developer preview version of VS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it currently stands (Windows 8 Developer Preview from Fall 2011), [WinRT doesn't allow you to dynamically load and execute code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7479902/536).