# C# - How to load dll at runtime in WinRT universal application

Tags: c#, dll, reflection, windows-runtime, windows

In .Net there is System.Reflection.Assembly.**LoadFrom("File location")** and System.Reflection.Assembly.**LoadFile("File location")**. In WinRT there is only System.Reflection.Assembly.**Load(System.Reflection.AssemblyName)**.
Then how do I load the dll files in WinRT?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic code execution on WinRT in Windows 8 (either C++ or .NET/C#)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473202/dynamic-code-execution-on-winrt-in-windows-8-either-c-or-net-c)

Comment: First off, the blog URL in the answer is obsolete.
Second, I've seen it before an app downloading and running dll's at runtime but I don't know how it's done. Maybe that was forbidden before in WinRT and then allowed after the updates made to it especially that this question was asked 4 years ago!

Comment: Sorry but a duplicate question... is still a duplicate question. If you think your question is not a duplicate then update your post and say why it is not a duplicate. By the way, the obsolete link in the other post has been updated to work now.

Answer (score 0):

From everything I have read on the internet, this is still not possible even in UWP.

I have created a feature request here:
https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/18145291-dynamically-load-assembly

It would be appreciated if you vote this feature up. Meantime, I don't think there is an answer to this question other than including the DLL in the AppX package (which is useless).

Comment: The DLL must be in your package so that static analysis can verify that you are not calling any functions that are disallowed in UWP apps.

Comment: That's the standard refrain from Microsoft. It makes no sense though. UWP as a runtime environment simply doesn't have "disallowed" APIs. They are simply excluded. So, if say for example, a DLL with "disallowed" APIs were included in the DLL, Windows UWP simply wouldn't be able to run them. UWP is a big boy, it could do a scan of the assembly at runtime to ensure that the APIs are supported. But even that is overkill. Other .NET platforms just throw an exception with "Method not found". Microsoft's reluctance to allow this is baffling in the extreme. Do they actually want apps built?

Comment: A DLL may exist only on PC and not exist on Phone, which makes it non-universal. And scanning the assembly at runtime isn't good enough because the assembly might do a memory scan to find functions to call rather than using GetProcAddress. Of course, you can bypass all the policy and just sideload your app, if you don't like the policy.

Comment: "A DLL may exist only on PC and not exist on Phone" - so what? It's the developers responsibility to make sure the DLL is available in all locations. It's the same if the file were a text file or an image. "the assembly might do a memory scan to find functions to call rather than using GetProcAddress". You've lost me on that one. What does that even mean?

Comment: Instead of using GetProcAddress, a program can manually parse the image metadata to find the functions it wants. The Store wants to be able to inventory the APIs used by a program so it can verify that, for example, it's not calling any undocumented functions, and if the program is found to be doing something bad, the program never makes it into the Store in the first place. (But as I noted, this is a Store policy. If you don't like Store policy, then don't go through the Store. Just sideload yourself.)

Comment: The Store policy is junk. UWP is a runtime environment. If the UWP runtime environment comes across an API it doesn't like, it doesn't have to run it. On Android, and iOS, assemblies can be loaded at runtime dynamically. Why can't UWP? Android and iOS apps are Store apps as well. But, sideloading has nothing to do with this. Even if I do side load, that doesn't magically give me the Assembly.Load method to load assemblies at runtime.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how Microsoft thinks they are going to get people to build for this platform... With all the gaping holes, they might as well dump platform.